# NumPy array indexing a 2D matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I've a little issue while working on same big data. But for now, let's assume I've got an NumPy array filled with zeros

```
>>> x = np.zeros((3,3))
>>> x
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Now I want to change some of these zeros with specific values. I've given the index of the cells I want to change.

```
>>> y = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]])
>>> y 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

And I've got an array with the desired (for now random) numbers, as follow

```
>>> z = np.array(np.random.rand(3))
>>> z
array([ 0.04988558,  0.87512891,  0.4288157 ])
```

So now I thought I can do the following:

```
>>> x[y] = z
```

But than it's filling the whole array like this

```
>>> x
array([[ 0.04988558,  0.87512891,  0.4288157 ],
       [ 0.04988558,  0.87512891,  0.4288157 ],
       [ 0.04988558,  0.87512891,  0.4288157 ]])
```

But I was hoping to get

```
>>> x
array([[ 0.04988558,           0,          0 ],
       [          0,  0.87512891,          0 ],
       [          0,           0,  0.4288157 ]])
```

**EDIT**

Now I've used a diagonal index, but what in the case my index is not just diagonal. I was hoping following works:

```
>>> y = np.array([[0,1],[1,2],[2,0]])
>>> x[y] = z
>>> x
>>> x
array([[          0,  0.04988558,          0 ],
       [          0,           0, 0.87512891 ],
          0.4288157,           0,          0 ]])
```

But it's filling whole array just like above

Comment: Indexing is zero-based.  Perhaps you want to change the elements `[0,0], [1,1], [2,2]`.

Comment: BrenBarn's solution is working. And you might want to change `y[z]=a` to `x[y]=z`

Comment: Made the changes you said, but than it's filling whole array as changed now in question

Comment: I had a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260806/indexing-multidimensional-arrays-with-an-array) and got an answer by Jaime explaining that (as a general rule) multidimensional arrays should be indexed with tuples.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Array indexing works a bit differently on multidimensional arrays

If you have a vector, you can access the first three elements by using

```
x[np.array([0,1,2])]
```

but when you're using this on a matrix, it will return the first few rows. Upon first sight, using

```
x[np.array([0,0],[1,1],[2,2]])]
```

sounds reasonable. However, NumPy array indexing works differently: It still treats all those indices in a 1D fashion, but returns the values from the vector in the same shape as your index vector.

To properly access 2D matrices you have to split both components into two separate arrays:

```
x[np.array([0,1,2]), np.array([0,1,2])]
```

This will fetch all elements on the main diagonal of your matrix. Assignments using this method is possible, too:

```
x[np.array([0,1,2]), np.array([0,1,2])] = 1
```

So to access the elements you've mentioned in your edit, you have to do the following:

```
x[np.array([0,1,2]), np.array([1,2,0])]
```

Comment: I'm quite happy that my guess was at least sounding reasonable. But thanks a lot for your clear answer, you're totally right

Comment: NumPy is quite efficient when it comes to complex indexing. Do you mean calable beyond RAM size? NumPy is not really suitable for out-of-core computations. But this is not the scope of this answer, please consider opening a proper SO question if you have one.