# IndexError: Too many indices when indexing array with another array

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I realize a lot of people have asked about this error, but I have yet to find anything that will help me.

This is my code:

```
def nanalyze(pupil, pw_sim):
    import numpy as np

    temp_s = abs(pw_sim)**2 * pupil

    vals_x, vals_y = np.where(pupil > 0)
    mask = pupil[vals_x[0]:vals_x[len(vals_x)-1], vals_y[0]:vals_y[len(vals_y)-1]]

    s_i = (np.mean(temp_s[tuple(mask)]**2) / (np.mean(temp_s[tuple(mask)])**2)) - 1
    return s_i
```

The second-to -last line,`s_i = (np.mean(temp_s[tuple(mask)]**2) / (np.mean(temp_s[tuple(mask)])**2)) - 1`, is what returns the index error: too many indices.

`pupil` and `pw_sim` are each arrays of shape `(1024,1024)`. `temp_s` is therefore also a `(1024,1024)` array and `mask` ends up being a `(1023,1023)` array. I've tried making `mask` a `(1024,1024)` to check and see if I'm getting the index error just because of the difference in shapes, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: What is this expected to do: `temp_s[tuple(mask)]` ?

Comment: It's supposed to index `temp_s` using `mask`. I translated this whole thing from Matlab code that had it as `temp_s(mask)`.

Comment: if you're creating a `tuple` - it can't be used as an index (to the best of my knowledge).

Comment: Hmm. I originally had it as just `temp_s[mask]` and I got a different error saying I couldn't use mask as an index. I actually found a [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260806/indexing-multidimensional-arrays-with-an-array) on this site which said that could be rectified by using a `tuple`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out that simplifying and using different syntax solved the problem. Now, rather than

```
vals_x, vals_y = np.where(pupil > 0)
mask = pupil[vals_x[0]:vals_x[len(vals_x)-1], vals_y[0]:vals_y[len(vals_y)-1]]

s_i = (np.mean(temp_s[tuple(mask)]**2) / (np.mean(temp_s[tuple(mask)])**2)) - 1
```

I have

```
temp_s_nz = np.mean(temp_s[pupil >0])
temp_sq_nz = np.mean(temp_s[pupil >0]**2)

s_i = (temp_sq_nz) / (temp_s_nz)**2 - 1
```

This change was made by my mentor, so I can't fully explain why it works, but I know that there are no longer any errors  and the code is easier to read. I think this works because of the way `pupil >0` is defined; in my original code there was room for error in it and now there is not. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read about numpy's [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), sometimes called "fancy indexing".

It's not clear from your question what you're trying to do with `temp_s[mask]`. If mask is really a mask, you'll need to make sure it has dtype `bool` and has the same shape as `temp_s`. If it's not a mask, you'll need to explain better what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that.  `mask` is a mask in terms of the module I'm using, but it is not a mask that would have dtype `bool`. All I know about `temp_s[mask]` is that it's supposed to index `temp_s` using `mask`.